# Electric and magnetic configuration on a plane perpendicular to the propagation

Tags: electromagnetism

I am not sure why the following configuration can not be a configuration of a electromagnetic wave.

[image]

I mean, i am sure it can not be the configuration of the fields in a plane perpendicular to a wave, but i can't explain the reason in a satisfactory way.

Look, it seems there are souces propagating with it, since these configurations are the configurations of a point electri ccharge and a infinite line with current. But i would like i better way to explain why we can't have it.

Comment: In this configuration, $\nabla \cdot E \neq 0$. This will reduced to $\Box \vec{E}=\rho$